# Moq MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd, moq

I'm trying to use Moq to mock MembershipProvider.  I get the following error

{"Access to the path 'C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\

I'm guessing that I'm not mocking the MembershipProvider properly.  Usually I do a mock.Object() to get the new mocked object but I'm unsure what to do with my mocked MembershipProvider.

```
[TestMethod]
public void LogUserIntoSystem_post_CorrectUsernameAndPassword()
{
    var model = new LoginModel
    {
        LoginName = "Bobby",
        Password = "bob",
        RememberMe = true
    };

    var membership = new Mock<MembershipProvider>();
    membership.Setup(x => x.ValidateUser("Bobby", "bob")).Returns(true);
    var controllerUnderTest = _testModel.ReturnController();

    //act
    controllerUnderTest.Login(model, string.Empty);

    //assert
    var actionResult = (RedirectToRouteResult)controllerUnderTest.Home();
    Assert.AreEqual("Home", actionResult.RouteValues["action"]);
    Assert.AreEqual("P", actionResult.RouteValues["controller"]);
}
```

Comment: What line gives you the error?

Comment: not familiar with Moq, but does Moq allow concrete classes to be mocked? MembershipProvider is not an interface.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see where you are using `MembershipProvider`

So from the outside in, it appears the controller is actually using a real or concrete MembershipProvider. Having checked on MSDN, the class is an abstract base class, so Moq should be fine to use with this class, though I would recommend a different approach.

```
class TwistedInfernosMembershipProvider : IMembershipProvider
{
    public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password) 
    { 
        // Call the real .NET membership provider here...
    }
}
```

Then in your controller I would do the following:

```
var testProvider = new Mock<IMembershipProvider>();
testProvider.Setup(x => x.ValidateUser("Bobby", "bob").Returns(true);
var subject = new ControllerUnderTest(testProvider.Object());
```

By doing this, you have abstracted the details of how you validate a user. You could switch this implementation out for any class that implements IMembershipProvider, your code nor tests would not even care. Also this means you can easily test your controller with this abstraction in place. Remember Moq needs an interface or base class/virtual methods in order to function correctly.

Check out this paper [PDF] on why you should [mock roles, and not objects](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://jmock.org/oopsla2004.pdf&ei=yuQgUfniDsSm4ASc2IDgCQ&usg=AFQjCNG1hoMD7NunoONsaOmVDgaQYkNmFA&sig2=_DeZ_Jfv2ijQDk_zI323yg&bvm=bv.42553238,d.bGE) for more information.